# how to delete git merge after some commits

Tags: git

I am working on a feature branch `us_stable` . I merged another branch `Proto` in this `us_stable` branch and after that I did some more commits and pushed to `us_stable` branch. Now I want to revert the branch which I merged in the begining. In my case I want to revert the changes which was merged in `Proto`. My Question is:

- Is it possible to revert that merge? If yes, how?

Comment: Since, `Git` uses SHA values to organize commits, so you can not delete an in-between merge.

Comment: There is no any in between merge. I created a myFeature branch and immediately merged another branch in it and then I started to work on myFeature branch and did 3 more commits and pushed to myFeature branch and merged. Now I want to ignore the changes which was merged.

Comment: The scenario you described is exactly what @ArslanAli meant by "in-between" merge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can issue the following command:

```
git rebase master -i
```

It selects only the commits that you want to have and discards the others.

Comment: I dont want to rebase myFeature branch. I just want to revert the merge I did in the beginning.

Comment: This answer is absolutely what you want to do. But maybe not on `master` but on the commit you started off your branch from.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git reset --hard abcdef123` to move your current branch to the commit *abcdef123*, for example to the commit just before the merge.

`git push --force` may be needed to push such branch.

See `git help reset` and [How to undo last commit(s) in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-to-undo-the-last-git-commit) for more info.